# Get all Cassandra query result in JSON format Using Java API

Tags: java, json, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Using query `select JSON * from table_name` in *cqlsh* I can get results in JSON format. I want to do the same using *Datastax* Java API.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("SELECT json * FROM ").append("JavaTest.data");
String query = sb.toString();
ResultSet rs = session.execute(query);
List<Row> rows = rs.all();
String q1 = rows.toString();
System.out.println(q1);
```

But the result is :

```
[  
   Row   [  
      {  
         "id":1,
         "time":"12",
         "value":"SALAM"
      }
   ],
   Row   [  
      {  
         "id":2,
         "time":" 89",
         "value":" BYE"
      }
   ],
   Row   [  
      {  
         "id":3,
         "time":" 897",
         "value":" HelloWorld"
      }
   ]
]
```

that it is not in the correct `JSON` format. I know I can get the `JSON` of a row but in that way, I should use a loop to get all results in `JSON` format. Searching in `JAVA API` Docs I couldn't find any solution for this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use following - just get JSON strings as is:

```
for (Row row : rs) {
    String json = row.getString(0);
    // ... do something with JSON string
}
```

If you want to represent them as the list of objects, then it could be easier to add square brackets before & after iteration, and put comma between JSON objects, like this:

```
    ResultSet rs = session.execute("select json * from test.jtest ;");
    int i = 0;
    System.out.print("[");
    for (Row row : rs) {
        if (i > 0)
            System.out.print(",");
        i++;
        String json = row.getString(0);
        System.out.print(json);
    }
    System.out.println("]");
```

Or you can write custom serializer for ResultSet, and put conversion task into it:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addSerializer(ResultSet.class, new ResultSetSerializer());
    mapper.registerModule(module);

    rs = session.execute("select * from test.jtest ;");
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(rs);
    System.out.println("'" + json + "'");
```

This is much more complex task (you need correctly handle collections, user-defined types etc.), but you may have better control over serialization.

Full code is available at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/alexott/68739e66551ea386e65b17cb91a41a32).  Please note that JSON serializer handles only NULL, boolean & int types - everything else is treated as string.  But it's enough to understand an idea.

Comment: As I said in the question, I don't want to use a loop. Isn't there any way to get JSON for the whole query result?

Comment: There is no such API ready to use... I would suggest to change approach - don't use JSON in SELECT, but marshall Rowset/Row into JSON...

Comment: Thanks, Can you give an example or source for that?